# iOS 10.3.2 : WebView is rendering differently as compared to Safari in same device

Tags: objective-c, input, swift3, webview, ios10.3.2

HTML input tag is not rendering properly. Input Tag is used like this :

```
<input type="file" name="fileImage" id="fileImage"  accept="image/*"/>
```

It works properly in Safari and allows to select only single image but with WebView it allows user to select multiple images. The same issue does not reproduce with iOS 10.2.1.